# How do I toggle autohotkey while in game?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm playing an online game and sometimes when i type autohotkey messes with my text.

How can i get it to ignore all my hotkeys when i press "enter" (which starts the chat) and turn back on when i press enter again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Suspend](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm) command. Based on your example, the following should work:

```
~Enter::Suspend, Toggle
```

Answer (score 2):

The above code is a delight.  As a complement to gamers using this do allow for a Suspend toggle key

> F12::Suspend

Its very helpful in case the suspend state might be in the wrong mode at the wrong time and also very useful if you do swap around windows frequently